# Is there a fix for font rendering in Chrome for Windows when using CSS3 transform to rotate text?

Tags: windows, css, google-chrome, transform

I'm using CSS3's transform to rotate some text at a -45deg angle:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate( -45deg );
transform: rotate( -45deg );
```

I've setup a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvalero/bcnLztcL/).

This works fine in all browsers I am targeting on a Mac, and almost all browsers on Windows. However, in Google Chrome for Windows I'm seeing issues with rendering.

At first I thought this was related to the graphics card and anti-aliasing, but seeing it render good in other browsers on the same machines, and seeing the issue only in Chrome for Windows on multiple machines I'm not so sure.

Is there a fix for this issue that anyone is aware of?

Comment: It looks absolutely fine to me.  Take a look at [this link here](http://imgur.com/uQ9gKKs) .  Or are you seeing something different from what I'm seeing.   The only visual blemish is that the anti-aliasing around the rotated font looks a *a little jagged* when compared to FF or IE. But not sufficiently bad to warrant any developer attention. I guess FF and IE just have better rotation algorithms.

Comment: I definitely see variance from machine to machine, but the anti-aliasing on what I'm seeing is a bit worse than what you're seeing. In some cases the letters appear lifted above or dropped below the others by about a 1/4 of the character height. I just find it very odd that it works great on Chrome for Mac and every other major browser on Mac or Windows, just not in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: Check that your Chrome install is up to date. I'm on `Version 36.0.1985.143 m`  You can also try validating and/or disabling Chrome's hardware and graphics acceleration.  `chrome://gpu/`  and then google for disabling certain features.